# Liouville Theorem or Maximum Modulus Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ and $g$ are two analytic functions on set $\Bbb C$ of all complex numbers such that

$$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$  for $n=1,2,3...$, then show that $f(z)=g(z)$ for each $z$ in $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: The set of zeros of the analytic function $f - g$ has an accumulation point at $0$.

Comment: Is it possible to use Liouville's theorem or Maximum modulus principle in this problem?

Comment: I doubt that Liouville is at all applicable, since it's really a statement that has to do with the behavior at large $|z|$. And maximum modulus is usually easiest to use with boundary values. Why do you ask?

Comment: ok. Then please elaborate on your hint. I can't get past the hint

Comment: @prat If the set of zeros of an analytic function has an accumulation point, then the analytic function is in fact identically zero.